# Why doesn't this Inline header compile?

Tags: c++, lnk2001

I come from a .NET and Java background, and I'm trying to create a simple scene manager for my game. It's an inline header file, and I'm getting errors compiling.

```
#pragma once
#include "Scene.h"
class SceneManager
{
private:
    static Scene currentScene;

public:    

    SceneManager()
    {
    }

    static void SetScene(Scene scene)
    {
        currentScene = scene;
    }

    static Scene GetScene()
    {
        return currentScene;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**: I am getting this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Scene SceneManager::currentScene" (?currentScene@SceneManager@@0VScene@@A) c:\Users\Justin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Noeron\Noeron\main.obj    Noeron
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Do you think maybe telling us what the errors are might be important?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: It does compile.  The header (or rather, the source file including it) compiles just fine.  What you're getting is a linker error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static member variables need to be not only declared, but defined. The declaration belongs in the header file, and the definition should go into a source file - you only want one of them in the entire program.

```
Scene SceneManager::currentScene;
```